# SyntaxError at /setups/new: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**my controller**:

```
class SetupsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @setup = Setup.new
    @todays_rate = @setup.todays_rates.build
  end


  def create
    @setup = Setup.new(params[:setup])
    if @setup.save
      redirect_to setup_path(@setup)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

end
```

**My view code: setup/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @setup, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <% if @setup.errors.any? %>
    <ul>
      <% @setup.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
        <li><strong><%= error %></strong></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>

  <h4><%= f.label :effective_from, class:'required' %>
    <%= f.text_field :effective_from %></h4>

  <h4><%= f.label :effective_to, class:'required' %>
    <%= f.text_field :effective_to %></h4>


  <%= f.fields_for(:todays_rate) do |i| %>  ##**combining two model with one view**


    <h1>Interest Rate</h1>
    <table cellpadding = "5px" cellspacing = "5px" width = "100%" class="table condensed-table"><tr>
      <h4><th>Days From</th>
        <th>Days To</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
        <th>Senior increment</th>
        <th>Super Senior increment</th>
        <th>Widow increment</th></h4>
    </tr>
      <h4><td><%= i.text_field :days_from, :class => 'input-mini'  %></td></h4>
      <h4> <td><%= i.text_field :days_to, :class => 'input-mini'  %></td></h4>
      <h4><td><%= i.text_field :rate, :class => 'input-mini'  %></td></h4>
      <h4> <td><%= i.text_field :senior_increment, :class => 'input-mini'  %></td></h4>
      <h4> <td><%= i.text_field :super_senior_increment,class:"input-mini"  %></td></h4>
      <h4><td><%= i.text_field :widow_incrtement,class: "input-mini" %></td></h4>
    </table>
  <% end %>
  <fieldset class="form-actions"> <%= f.submit "Create Customer", class: "btn btn-primary" %></field>
```

**setup.rb mmodel**:

```
class Setup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todays_rates
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :todays_rates
  attr_accessible :effective_from, :effective_to, :todays_rate
end
```

i'm combining two model in one view but i'm getting the above error. i don't know where i missed the keyword_end.can any one help me

Comment: You are missing `<%end%>` after `f.submit` in your `new.html.erb`

Comment: @Pavan: corrected..but getting same error

Comment: The same error? Add another one=) Actually, provide log at the end of the post, not in title.

Comment: Did you restarted the server after that? And this line `<%= f.fields_for(:todays_rate) do |i| %>` should be like this `<%= f.fields_for :todays_rates do |i| %>`.Note the **`plural`** change in `todays_rates`

Comment: @Pavan: thanks i changed the line and restarted server but it shows "syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end" error in  "/setups/new".is there any other solution!

Comment: This **might** have got downvoted (not by me) because it's very similar to a dozen other questions btw.

Comment: yeah its downvoted.it might be similar question but i didn't get answer yet.im new to ruby on rails.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you haven't closed the form, ie you need a `<% end %>` at the end of your template.

The error sort of tells you that, though the tIDENTIFIER stuff can throw one off the scent a bit.